# Where do I find the license terms for fonts included in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, licensing

Although an answer to the question in the header is desirable, my actual needs are a little more specific:

An organization I'm involved in has adopted as one of its logotypes a capital F set in the standard `\mathfrak` font - in other words, to print our logo on a paper, one would simply do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
{\huge $\mathfrak{F}$}
\end{document}
```

and compile with LaTeX. (This would of course still be quite small compared to sizes we normally use, but it's good enough for an MWE...)

Now, we are thinking about protecting our name, our logos etc legally. Is this something we could have a right to do? We haven't figured out what license terms apply to the font, and if there would be any license costs involved with doing this, we might want to leave this logo outside the protection claim (the organization is quite small and non-profit).

---

And by the way: Yes, I understand very well that you who answer this might not be a lawyer. However, finding the actual license terms for the font would be a good place to start if/when we consult an actual laywer...

Comment: Look into [TeX Gyre Fonts](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre) License for [example](ftp://sunsite.icm.edu.pl/pub/CTAN/help/Catalogue/licenses.gfsl.html). I think, that's a good start. Also, [this](ftp://sunsite.icm.edu.pl/pub/CTAN/help/Catalogue/licenses.html) document.

Comment: I could do you a nice calligraphic fraktur `F` in TikZ if the font licence isn't suitable ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please do try to make your MWE error free:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 {\huge \mathfrak
```

adding

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

produces

```
! LaTeX Error: \mathfrak allowed only in math mode.
```

Adding the math markup finally shows

```
....\U/euf/m/n/20.74 F
```

so it is the AMS Euler font which is distributed under the SIL font licence as stated here:

http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/fonts/amsfonts/doc/OFL.txt

Comment: Thanks - I guess I was a little too quick on adding that MWE...